# Can't install libqt4-webkit on CENTOS 5.6 x86_64

Tags: centos5

I want to install CutyCapt to capture screenshots from websites, on my server!
I need to install libqt first,

But I cant install it. I I run the command bellow

```
yum install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev
```

I get this:

```
root@server [/downloads]# yum install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 already installed and latest version
No package libqt4-webkit available.
No package libqt4-dev available.
Nothing to do
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the answers, you'll see this:

> New Qt4.4 Packages are available
>   for CentOS (EL5 Distros) in this repo:
>
> http://packages.atrpms.net/dist/el5/

You need to add this repository to your package repository list. Otherwise you can't get the packages.

Comment: Error 404 - page not found